# Python2 + 3 : How to install modules for Python3 installed from sources and offline?

Tags: python, linux, installation, offline, python-module

I'm using RedHat Linux 6 and currently I only have 2.6.X version available from internal Linux repository. So I installed **Python2 package(s) from repository** and in parallel I installed **python3 from sources into /opt directory** :

```
$ ll /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Jul  4 15:04 /usr/bin/python3 -> /opt/python-3.5.2/bin/python3
```

Problem is now that I don't know **how to install modules for Python3 installed from sources and so not in default directory** (modules for Python2 are installed from internal repository) without breaking Python 2 install.

Moreover **the server does not have access to internet**.

How could I manage my Python 3 install to get modules ? I read multiple docs but I cannot figure out how to proceed.

Thx, 
Tom

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your "python.exe" in your python3 install folder into "python3.exe". Make sure you can use "python" to start Python2 and "pyhton3" to start python3.
2. For Python3, use the command `python3 -m pip`

Comment: Thx. However I need/must keep Python2 available as well.

Comment: Unfortunaltely cannot find pip3 : $ python3 -m pip
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

Comment: @user3566182 - Check out have you installed pip with your Python3 in that folder. If not, download the package [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/8.1.2)and install it manually.   You can also use `find / -name "pip*"` to check whether your Python3 is fully installed.

Comment: I finally managed to get pip3 by recompiling my Python 3.5.2 with `--with-ensurepip=install` option set :
`./configure --prefix=/opt/python-3.5.2 --with-zlib=/usr/include --with-ensurepip=install`. I'm now able to run it `sudo python3 -m pip install mypackage`. I'm testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtualenv to built individual enviroment for different python version, then install thirdparty libraries with offline install package.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have downloaded python from source e.g.
`tar -zxvf python-3.6.3.tgz`
`cd python-3.6.3.tgz`
`./configure`
`make`
`make install`

Now rename python to python3
`mv python python3`

Now install the module
`./python3 -m pip install pandas`